# how to call JavaScript from controllers in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

in my research I found that one can use this method:

```
$this->registerJsFile()
```

However, when I use it I get this error:

> Calling unknown method:
>   frontend\controllers\AvailableController::registerJs()

Comment: You should follow MVC design pattern, js is related to views

Answer (score 1):

The method:

```
registerJs($url, $options = [], $key = null)
```

is defined in the *yii2/web/View* class. The *$this* object in your example is an instance of your *AvailableController* class, that presumably extends  the *Controller* class. That's why you get the error.
You should use the *$this* object of one of your views. 
Try to go to to your *views/available*  folder, open a view there (for example, *view.php*), identify your *$this* object, and call  *registerJs()* from there.